# Error when trying to import matplotlib: "import is not recognized as internal or external command"

Tags: python, anaconda

On my Anaconda navigator, `matplotlib` is installed however when I run `import matplotlib` it will give me an error message saying: "import is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Did I not download it? How do I check that I've successfully installed it?

Answer (score 0):

You are not running `import matplotlib` in a python interpreter.

Run python.exe first

Comment: Hi Mihai Andrei, I did try it in both python interpreter and command prompt.

Comment: when I import matplotlib on python.exe this following show